# Block failure on If and For

Tags: excel, vba

I created several loop and if statement to copy and paste data based on certain condition , however it just wont detect the block. "Compile Error : End If without block If"

Spend 2 hour repeatedly reading my own code , IDK how to proceed from here.I tried removing what is said to be "End if without block if" and Next without For only to be greeted by compile error.

```
i = 0
For Each file In file_list
    If Not file.Name Like "~*" Then
        Set book = Workbooks.Open(file)
        book.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
            row_file = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
            MsgBox (row_file)
        For colum = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NANI").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            header = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NANI").Cells(1, colum)

            If Not IsFormula(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NANI").Cells(2, colum)) Then
                For colum_file = 1 To Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                    book.Activate
                    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
                    'MsgBox (Cells(1, colum_file))
                    If LCase(Cells(1, colum_file)) = LCase(header) Then
                         Range(Cells(2, colum_file), Cells(Rows.Count, colum_file).End(xlUp)).Copy
                         ThisWorkbook.Activate
                         If i = 0 Then
                            Cells(Rows.Count, colum).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                            i = 1
                         Else
                            Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(-(row_file) + 2, colum - 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                         End If 'Counter for paste type'
                         book.Activate
                         Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
                         Exit For 'Exit loop and check next header'
                    End If 'If header are equal'
            End If 'Skiping formula block be autofill checker'
        Next colum_file 'next colum seek'
    Next colum 'next colum of main file'
    End If 'File name checker'
    i = 0 'res counter'
Next file  'next file'
```

I got several source file which I want to combine based on header where data only have more or the same amount of variable and arrangement of header.Also I am skipping the "header check" if the first data (second row) is a form of formula since it does not exist in the source and are to be filled with auto fill latter on. 
Expecting it to compile.

Also the formula for IsFormula is

```
Function IsFormula(Check_Cell As Range)
IsFormula = Check_Cell.HasFormula
End Function
```

Comment: Shouldn't these two lines  `End If 'Skiping formula block be autofill checker'` and
        `Next colum_file 'next colum seek'` be in reverse order? Or am I missing something? The `Next` should come first and the `End if` should follow.

Comment: Glad I could help. I posted the solution as an answer for the sake of completeness. Please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following two lines of code should be in reverse order:

```
End If 'Skiping formula block be autofill checker'
Next colum_file 'next colum seek'
```

So basically the right way to do it should be:

```
'
'the rest of your code...
'
Next colum_file 'next colum seek'
End If 'Skiping formula block be autofill checker'
'
'the rest of your code
'
```

Comment: You beat me toi it!  ;o)